# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'profile_picture') in vue.js component Laravel 9

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs3

Environment
Laravel v9 + vite, PHP 8.1, vue3, VPS linux distro. UBUNTU

[image]

I am having this error in the vue.js component of my Laravel project,it says that the profile_picture has a null value in the object but I also put the check for this

```
       <div v-if="typeof rep.user.profile_picture != null">
      <img :src="rep.user.profile_picture" :alt="rep.user.name" class="commenter-image rounded-circle"/>
       </div>
        <div v-else>
        <img src="/assets/images/user-placeholder-1.jpg" alt="Commenter-placeholder" class="commenter-image rounded-circle"/>
       </div>
```

I have carefully searched for this profile_picture property in the file it's not anywhere else except this. but still having this issue
also, it doesn't have any relation with the sweetalert2 library but still, console is pointing to this library
Any thoughts about this error??
extra help meterial>>

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like in some `rep` objects, `user` property is null. Can you please verify that all the objects in an array contains a value in `user` property.

You can use [`optional chaining (?.)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator :

```
v-if="rep?.user?.profile_picture !== null"
```

Comment: yes all of the objects have a user object and a profile_picture property which is null, and there are only 2 main objects so i am clear about it,

Comment: @ZeeshanAwan In that case it should not give the error which you mentioned in the post. Are we adding user properly later based on any manipulations/calculations ?

Comment: yes, i am sure that every comment object has the user's nested object in it because it is manually coded from the backend controller,  I have tried your solution but still have a problem. sometimes it doesn't show up in the development environment but in production, it remains still, I am unable to understand where is the mistake, which  is causing  this error, i am  checking all of the objects but still having the issue , iam going to update the question with vue js component code you can have a look

Comment: I fixed the code by adding "?" in all places where I was trying to access the user object
even in the alt attribute of img, it is strange but there should be no need for adding this operator inside of img tag which is inside of the v-if condition because img tag was only rendering if the condition become true either wise else condition img tag to have no variables trying to access user object, 
but still to fix this i have to put this operator inside of the v-if statement's img tag

Answer (score 2):

The condition `v-if="typeof rep.user.profile_picture != null"` doesn't work because `typeof rep.user.profile_picture` returns `object`. So I would suggest you to change this condition to

```
v-if="rep.user.profile_picture !== null"
```

or even

```
v-if="rep.user && rep.user.profile_picture !== null"
```

Comment: I am checking typeOf  rep.user.profile_picture which a  property with null value in object 
typeOf will be  returning  "object" if i was checking rep.user  which is object as you can see in last screenshot attached with question